# Magento 2 HTML minfi / delete comments

Tags: magento2, html, pagespeed

I want to automatically delete comments in the programm code, mostly HTML.

Like:

Best would be a Plug-ins which leaves the comments as long its deactivated.

We are using Magento Speed from Potato Commerce and i thought the HTML minifi function would do this job. But its not.

Any ideas?